# Thymeleaf th:switch with th:each

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How to apply th:each on th:switch for values from Enum in following case?

```
public enum Framework {
    ABC0(0, "Name0"),
    ABC1(1, "Name1"),
    ABC2(2, "Name2"),
    ABC3(3, "Name3");

    public int id;
    public String name;

    private Framework (int id, String name){
            this.id = id;    
            this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and in model class I have a field:

```
private int frameworkId;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - it is quite simple.

I passed values of Framework to form in Controller class:

```
model.addAttribute("frameworks", Framework.values());
```

and then:

```html
<span class="cls">Framework:</span>
<span th:switch="${item.frameworkId}">
    <span th:each="fw : ${frameworks}">
        <span th:case="${fw.id}" th:text="${fw.name}"></span>
    </span>             
</span>
```